# Setting Column Width as Percent in RichFaces 4.x ExtendedDataTable

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a problem with RichFaces 4: I can't give percentual value for column width in RichFaces 4, it is simply ignored. 
If I set the width as em or px, it works.

Here is what I tried for rich:column:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable ... >
  <rich:column width="20%" ...> <!-- width 20% is ignored -->
  </rich:column>
</<rich:extendedDataTable>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `<rich:column style="width:20%" />`

Comment: Setting the style this way doesn't work for me. The style is only applied to the table body's <td>s, but since the body isn't defined with style="width:100%" (and I've found no way to do so), the columns don't fill the available space. Further, the header is still fixed and styled using a (pre-computed?) css block. I've found no way to remove those, either (the headerClass attribute only styles the full header...)

Answer (score 0):

Try using style attribute along with richface tag like
`<rich:column style="width:100%;"/>`. This should work or else use **columnClass or styleClass** attribute and give the same style info in your css part.

If nothing works try giving the width size in pixels.